# Unable to install CytoNorm and scrabbitR packages in R 4.2.2. Is there any other way? Thanks

Tags: r, package

I'm new to data science and am trying to generate UMAPs from flow cytometry data. I'm following the guides here - https://immunedynamics.io/pdfs/discovery.pdf and here - http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/scDataviz/inst/doc/scDataviz.html

I'm trying to install CytoNorm and scrabbitR packages, but I keep getting the following errors -

```
remotes::install_github("saeyslab/CytoNorm")
```

> ERROR: dependency ‘CytoML’ is not available for package ‘CytoNorm’

```
BiocManager::install("CytoNorm")
```

> Warning message:
> package ‘CytoNorm’ is not available for Bioconductor version '3.16'

> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Similar errors when I use

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/saeyslab/CytoNorm")
# OR
install.packages("CytoNorm")
```

I get errors saying it's not available for this version of R. I checked the package files and it says version needs to be >=3.5, so I think it shouldn't be a problem with R 4.2.2 that I have, but it still shows these errors.

I get the same errors for scrabbitR package too, I tried all these methods. I really don't know what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated, thanks!!